# IAP bootloader not jumping to the application address

Tags: stm32, bootloader, firmware, update

I am working on IAP in STM32F4. I received .bin file using uart and flash it in 0x08004000 address successfully and disable irq , set msp , set vector, deinit hal , reset the systick registers but the jump is not working, It just freezes there. Can anyone help me with this?

## define APP_ADDRESS 0x08004000

[image: snip of jump code]

Comment: Make sure that the application binary is compiled for the proper base address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The problem is with the user application. I build the application at correct address but the SCB->VTOR register is overwritten to offset zero from the call of  SystemInit() in the application code. So I changed the VECT_OFFSET value in system_stm32f4xx.c file and everything works fine. 
Anyway, thank you for all the suggested answers.

Comment: Does anyone know how to neglect manual file alteration and where to put SCB->VTOR in application or how to disable it?

Answer (score 1):

It is far not enough. You need to disable all interrupts in the NVIC.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Because if the application reenables the interrupts the enabled in the NVIC interrupt might not be handled by the app code causing the HF. Rule of thumb: before passing the control to the app make sure that the uC is in the same state as after the reset

Comment: While it may not have been the *immediate* issue here, there is truth to this concern.  So much, in fact, that the best practice when a bootloader has used the chip in a more than trivial way is generally considered to be to set a flag in the RCC or ram, perform a reset, see the flag, and branch to the application code before doing any configuration which would then have to be undone.